# Convert string of tuple of numbers to complex number

Tags: string-manipulation, complex, input

I am reading complex number from a file which gives me a list like that

```
{"(-0.00152709,-0.000650355)", "(7.05005e-06,-4.80275e-07)", "(2.77004e-05,-3.794e-06)",...}
```

Here, every element in the list is a tuple of two real numbers representing the real and imaginary part of complex number.
I want to convert this list to a list of complex numbers.
How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls = {"(-0.00152709,-0.000650355)", "(7.05005e-06,-4.80275e-07)", "(2.77004e-05,-3.794e-06)"};

Complex@@Interpreter["Number"][StringSplit[#, "(" | ")" | ","]] & /@ ls
```

> (* {-0.00152709 - 0.000650355 I, 7.05005*10^-6 - 4.80275*10^-7 I, 
>    0.0000277004 - 3.794*10^-6 I}*)

Answer (score 1):

Or, First map the string to the form of a valid complex number string, then use the appropriate Interpreter

```
lst={"(-0.00152709,-0.000650355)","(7.05005e-06,-4.80275e-07)","(2.77004e-05,-3.794e-06)"};

Map[(Interpreter["SemanticComplexNumber"]@StringReplace[#,"("~~a__~~","~~b__~~")":>a<>" + "<>b<>" I"])&,lst]
```