# Convert tuples to numbers

Tags: list-manipulation

The link
[Convert string of tuple of numbers to complex number](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207536/convert-string-of-tuple-of-numbers-to-complex-number) is perhaps a bit too advanced for me to understand, but I wonder if there is some easy way to convert tuples to integers, e.g.

```
lst = Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 4];
```

would become

```
{ 1111, 1112, 1113, ... }
```

A most basic (and naive) method is

```
For[i = 1, i <= Length[lst], i++,
 s = 1000 lst[[i, 1]] + 100 lst[[i, 2]] + 10 lst[[i, 3]] + lst[[i, 4]];
 Print[s]
 ]
```

but I'm sure there is a much smarter way. TIA.

Comment: Something like `FromDigits /@ Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 4]`?

Comment: Many thanks. So short and elegant.

Comment: Just a note: the choice of base in `FromDigits` can matter here if this is meant to be a reversible transformation, particularly if your tuples contain numbers bigger than 9 or less than 1.

Comment: Another possibility is: `lst . {1000, 100, 10, 1}`, which ought to be pretty fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**(a) [NumberCompose](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberCompose.html)**

```
lst = Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 4];

NumberCompose[#,{1000, 100, 10, 1}]&/@lst//Short

(* {1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1121, 1122, 1123, <<246>>, 4442, 4443, 4444} *)
```

(According to the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberCompose.html), "the basic operation of `NumberDecompose` is `Dot`")

**(b)  [Dot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html)**

(Contributed by [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll), in a comment)

```
lst.{1000, 100, 10, 1}//Short

(*{1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1121, 1122, 1123, <<246>>, 4442, 4443, 4444}*)
```

**(c) [FromDigits](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromDigits)**

(Contributed by 
[J. M.'s slightly less busy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m-s-slightly-less-busy) in a comment)

```
FromDigits/@lst//Short

(* {1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1121, 1122, 1123, <<246>>, 4442, 4443, 4444} *)
```

[eyorble](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/52935/eyorble) has noted (in a comment) that "the choice of base in `FromDigits` can matter here if this is meant to be a reversible transformation, particularly if your tuples contain numbers bigger than 9 or less than 1"

**Community Wiki**

I think this question deserves a 'fully-fledged' answer, judging by the highly voted comments: it may benefit future visitors, for example.  I have marked this answer "Community Wiki". Feel free to edit.